# Umbraco how to create account related pages?

Tags: asp.net-membership, umbraco, webforms

I would like to create some pages related to a member account in umbraco 4.
In asp.net webforms, an account folder is created and in it are the account related pages, such as Login.aspx, ForgotPassword.aspx, etc...
Now, these pages are not actual *content* pages, but are more of the adminitrative type.

I've created user controls for the login, register, etc.

Should I create a document type in umbraco for each page type, and put the respective user control in each template ? what is the recommended way to do this in umbraco ?

Answer (score 0):

On the content manager, just right click on the page or node you want to protect, right click on and select "Public Access".

In there you can apply permissions to individual users and/or roled based. The Roled based one will require for you to have "Member Groups".

That is it. All the security is kept on the "\App_Data\access.config" file; you can review it for more details on how they are achieving this.

hth,

-covo